Are there any structures that have a simple orthorhombic lattice?
There seems to be very little discussion about these online and the few sources I've found say that they only exist as a mathematical definition. I've seen some sources claiming that Rhombic sulfur is an example, but based on the images I've seen it doesn't seem to line up with the definition

The crystal structure is rhombic but it has a large basis (128? atoms).

What do you mean by "simple orthorhombic"? Do you mean "primitive orthorhombic"? Ideally can you tell us which space groups you are interested in? Then we can just search a database...

Wikipedia lists all the orthorhombic space groups and gives a number of examples. Do any of these meet your criteria? If not, why not?

I'm referring to a structure that's box shaped, with right inter-axial angles, and has a particle in each corner of but 3 different side lengths

"Simple" lattice structures with a single-atom basis, meaning atoms only at the lattice points, are rare because just occupying those lattice points results in an inefficient packing. In practice, simple lattices in nature generally come with a multiple-atom basis in order to fill space more efficiently, or assuming a simple lattice leads to fractional occupations that require a nonsimple lattice (e.g. face-centered) to describe.
Examples of using a multiple-atom basis include (ortho)rhombic sulfur, with a simple lattice but 128 atoms in its basis, and more simply caesium chloride ($\ce{CsCl}$) which is simple cubic with a two-atom basis (because of the ordered alternation between caesium and chloride ions the eight-coordinate structure is not body-centered cubic). An apparent simple lattice that's not actually simple is given by the fluorite structure in calcium fluoride ($\ce{CaF2}$) or magnesium silicide ($\ce{Mg2Si}$). In these compounds the fluorine or magnesium that constitutes the majority of the atoms are arranged as if in a simple cubic lattice, but the alternating occupation of the centers of the cubes by calcium or silicon is described properly by rendering the lattice face-centered cubic instead, with a (collinear!) three-atom basis.
A rare example of a single-atom, simple lattice structure is simple cubic $\alpha$-polonium.

You might be referring to Primitive orthorhomic lattice (in Pearson symbol, it would be oP). There are few examples having this lattice:

Cementite ($\ce{Fe3C}$)
Forsterite ($\ce{Mg2SiO4}$)
$\ce{KNbO3}$

